# Why my Next.js getUsers route only works in local but not in deploy

Tags: next.js, routes

The problem im having is that my **/api/users** only get real data updates from my firestore in development, but when I deploy the project, if I try to acess myproject.com/api/users, the data is the current data when it builds, so if I add more users, the route doesn't update.
Probably a simple thing but Im newbie in Next.js

```
Project Structure:
├── app
  ├── api
   └── getUsers
    └── route.ts
 ├── randomPage
  └── page.tsx
├── public
├── .env
├── middleware.ts
├── next.config.mjs
├── README.md
```

and the **route.ts** code:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { db } from "../../../firebaseConfig";
import { DocumentData, collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

export async function GET() {
  try {
    const users = await getAllUsers();
    return NextResponse.json(users);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Erro ao obter usuários:", error);
    return NextResponse.error();
  }
}

async function getAllUsers() {
  const usersCollection = collection(db, "users");

  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(usersCollection);

  const users: DocumentData[] = [];

  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    users.push(doc.data());
  });

  return users;
}
```